# Read HTML Table Into Data Frame with Hyperlinks in R

Tags: html, r, xml, hyperlink, rvest

I am trying to read an HTML table from a publicly-accessible website into a data frame in R. The final column of the table contains hyperlinks, and I would like to read these hyperlinks into the table rather than the text that is displayed on the webpage. I've reviewed several posts here on StackOverflow and on other sites and have gotten almost there, but I haven't been able to read the hyperlinks themselves.

The table I'm trying to read is here: http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12300&reportTitle=LMPs%20by%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Load%20Zones%20and%20Trading%20Hubs&showHTMLView=&mimicKey.

The final column contains hyperlinks that point to the actual data in *.ZIP file format for download. I've managed to read the table into R as text, but I can't figure out how to resolve the hyperlinks in the final column.

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(XML)
webURL <- 'http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12300&reportTitle=LMPs%20by%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Load%20Zones%20and%20Trading%20Hubs&showHTMLView=&mimicKey'
page <- htmlParse( webURL )
tableNodes <- getNodeSet( sitePage, "//table" )
myTable <- readHTMLTable( tableNodes[[3]] )
```

However, this contains the text in the final column, not the hyperlink. How do I replace the word "zip" in the final column of this table in R with the values for the corresponding hyperlink in each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will let you target either the XML files or the CSV files and you get the filename as well as the URL so you can then iterate over the URLs and filenames and save them with names you'll recognize later on.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

pg <- read_html("http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12300&reportTitle=LMPs%20by%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Load%20Zones%20and%20Trading%20Hubs&showHTMLView=&mimicKey")

csv_fils <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//td[contains(@class, 'labelOptional_ind') and contains(., 'csv')]/..")

data_frame(
  fil_name = html_nodes(csv_fils, "td.labelOptional_ind") %>% html_text(),
  url = html_nodes(csv_fils, xpath=".//td[4]/div/a") %>% html_attr("href")
) -> csv_df

glimpse(csv_df)
## Observations: 1,560
## Variables: 2
## $ fil_name <chr> "cdr.00012300.0000000000000000.20170729.094015151.LMPSROSNODENP6788_20170729_094011_csv.zip", "cdr...
## $ url      <chr> "/misdownload/servlets/mirDownload?mimic_duns=&doclookupId=572923018", "/misdownload/servlets/mirD...

xml_fils <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//td[contains(@class, 'labelOptional_ind') and contains(., 'xml')]/..")

data_frame(
  fil_name = html_nodes(xml_fils, "td.labelOptional_ind") %>% html_text(),
  url = html_nodes(xml_fils, xpath=".//td[4]/div/a") %>% html_attr("href")
) -> xml_df

glimpse(xml_df)
## Observations: 1,560
## Variables: 2
## $ fil_name <chr> "cdr.00012300.0000000000000000.20170729.094015016.LMPSROSNODENP6788_20170729_094011_xml.zip", "cdr...
## $ url      <chr> "/misdownload/servlets/mirDownload?mimic_duns=&doclookupId=572923015", "/misdownload/servlets/mirD...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your response. I was missing how to generate the xpath argument. Can you explain a bit about how you generated this parameter by looking at the HTML or point me to some reading material that describes this? I need to do a similar task for several other websites that will likely have slightly different HTML table structures.

Comment: Glad it worked for your use-case! I did a view-source (inspect-element can lead to wrong selectors) and noticed the table structure. It's not the best `<table>` design, but I also figured you'd want CSV or XML (not both) since they likely contain the same data, just in different representations. If it were me, I'd want the name and URL. So I figured out how to target the right `<tr>`'s by the first XPath (check for that `<td>` & go 1 up the element tree). Then grab the 1st `<td>` for each of those `<tr>`'s for the name and the 4th for the URL. It takes some time to get used to hunting XPath.

Comment: Thank you for another excellent explanation. I had tried inspect-element to no avail after reading another post, but this makes sense. Indeed I'm just looking to download the CSVs and I want to track the title and the filename to reference in the future so I can harvest only the files I don't already have, so your solution fit the bill 100%. Your explanation about finding the desired `<td>` and going one-up the element tree from there will help me do this more generally in the future.

Again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I find using the rvest package easier than XML.

Here is a solution to obtain a list of the links:

```
webURL <- 'http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12300&reportTitle=LMPs%20by%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Load%20Zones%20and%20Trading%20Hubs&showHTMLView=&mimicKey'

library(rvest)

page<-read_html(webURL)
links<-page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I've selected the answer from hrbrmstr because it was more comprehensive and flexible for scraping other websites in a similar fashion.