# Read URLs for CSV files into vector

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

This question is similar to the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385500/read-html-table-into-data-frame-with-hyperlinks-in-r). I've tried the techniques from the answer, but for some reason I'm getting no matches to my `xpath` and am looking for some additional guidance.

I am trying to scrape the URLs of all the downloadable CSV files from the following webpage: [Page with CSV Files](https://marketplace.spp.org/pages/rtbm-lmp-by-location#%2F2017%2F11%2FBy_Day). Here's what I've tried so far.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

myURL <- 'https://marketplace.spp.org/pages/rtbm-lmp-by-location#%2F2017%2F11%2FBy_Day'

attempt1 <- read_html( myURL ) %>%
  html_nodes( xpath='//*[contains(@class, "f-csv")]/..' ) %>%
  html_attr('href')

attempt2 <- read_html( myURL ) %>%
  html_nodes( xpath='//*[contains(@class, "files") and contains(@href, ".csv")]' ) %>%
  html_attr('href')
```

Both attempts return empty character vectors. The calls to `html_nodes()` both return lists of zero elements.

When I search for the `filemanager` class in the page, I get a nonempty list, but I'm having trouble drilling down further.

This returns a non-empty list:

```
filemanager <- read_html( myURL ) %>%
  html_nodes( xpath='//*[contains(@class, "filemanager")]' )
```

From right-clicking the download icon, I see the URL for the file dated 2017-11-01 (note the filename is different from the displayed update time) should be: https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=%2F2017%2F11%2FBy_Day%2FRTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171101.csv. This downloads the CSV for me when I click it.

Any thoughts on how to return the download URLs for the CSV files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site makes an XHR request and dynamically builds those blocks, so no amount of plain web scraping is going to work.

Hack-grabbing the XHR request that it makes isn't going to work either b/c the site is coded semi-well and has extensive CSRF protection.

So, we need to get one normal page of the site which has CSRF metadata in it, extract those tokens, *then* make a faux XHR request to the same target the page does.

The site was also pretty uniform (another sign they did OK w/r/t building the site/app) so it was fairly easy to make a generic function that lets you input year, month and "type" (I made some guesses based on the info in the 'boxes' on the site) and get a list of the contents of the CSV files back as data frames. By default, it uses the current year and month and defaults to "`By_Day`".

The CSVs take a bit to download, so it prints a message for each one as it downloads. You may not need that functionality, but it shld be straightforward to do what you need with the initial XHR response.

I tried to keep the dependencies to a minimum, but `purrr` and `dplyr` wld make for (IMO) better additions.

```
rtbm_lmp_by_location <- function(year = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"),
                                 month = format(Sys.Date(), "%m"),
                                 by_type = c("By_Day", "By_Interval", "RePrice")) {

  require(rvest)
  require(jsonlite)
  require(httr)

  by_type <- match.arg(by_type, c("By_Day", "By_Interval", "RePrice"))

  res <- GET("https://marketplace.spp.org/pages/rtbm-lmp-by-location")
  doc <- content(res)

  x_csrf_token <- html_attr(html_node(doc, "meta[id='_csrf']"), "content")
  x_spp_csrf_token <- html_attr(html_node(doc, "meta[id='_spp_csrf']"), "content")

  POST(
    url = "https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/", 
    add_headers(
      Host = "marketplace.spp.org", 
      Referer = "https://marketplace.spp.org/pages/rtbm-lmp-by-location",
      `X-CSRF-TOKEN` = x_csrf_token,
      `X-SPP-CSRF-TOKEN` = x_spp_csrf_token,
      `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest"
    ), 
    body = list(
      name = "rtbm-lmp-by-location",
      fsName = "rtbm-lmp-by-location", 
      type = "folder", 
      path = sprintf("/%s/%s/%s", year, month, by_type)
    ), 
    encode = "json"
  ) -> res

  res <- content(res, as="text")
  res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res, flatten=TRUE)
  res$path <- sprintf("https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=%s",
                      res$path)

  lapply(res$path, function(.x) {
    message(sprintf("Downloading <%s>...", .x))
    read.csv(.x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

}

fils <- rtbm_lmp_by_location()
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171101.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171102.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171103.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171104.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171105.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171106.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171107.csv>...
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171108.csv>...
```

And, here's the data it pulled back:

```
str(fils)
## List of 8
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/01/2017 00:05:00" "11/01/2017 00:05:00" "11/01/2017 00:05:00" "11/01/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/01/2017 05:05:00" "11/01/2017 05:05:00" "11/01/2017 05:05:00" "11/01/2017 05:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 16.2 18 21.3 15.9 21.4 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 0.8342 0.3078 0.0295 0.5966 -0.1799 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0 2.34 5.94 0 6.19 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 15.3 15.3 15.3 15.3 15.3 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/02/2017 00:05:00" "11/02/2017 00:05:00" "11/02/2017 00:05:00" "11/02/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/02/2017 05:05:00" "11/02/2017 05:05:00" "11/02/2017 05:05:00" "11/02/2017 05:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 17.1 16.7 16.6 16.8 16.4 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 0.5527 0.1549 0.0498 0.2766 -0.1663 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 16.6 16.6 16.6 16.6 16.6 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/03/2017 00:05:00" "11/03/2017 00:05:00" "11/03/2017 00:05:00" "11/03/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/03/2017 05:05:00" "11/03/2017 05:05:00" "11/03/2017 05:05:00" "11/03/2017 05:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 18.9 18.3 17.8 18.6 17.5 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 0.819 0.191 -0.221 0.566 -0.584 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.0076 0 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 18.1 18.1 18.1 18.1 18.1 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/04/2017 00:05:00" "11/04/2017 00:05:00" "11/04/2017 00:05:00" "11/04/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/04/2017 05:05:00" "11/04/2017 05:05:00" "11/04/2017 05:05:00" "11/04/2017 05:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 0.0107 4.4038 5.2691 0.0108 5.1795 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 3e-04 2e-04 0e+00 4e-04 -1e-04 1e-04 -1e-04 0e+00 1e-04 3e-04 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0 4.39 5.26 0 5.17 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 0.0104 0.0104 0.0104 0.0104 0.0104 0.0104 0.0104 0.0104 0.0105 0.0104 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 283800 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:283800] "11/05/2017 00:05:00" "11/05/2017 00:05:00" "11/05/2017 00:05:00" "11/05/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:283800] "11/05/2017 05:05:00" "11/05/2017 05:05:00" "11/05/2017 05:05:00" "11/05/2017 05:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:283800] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:283800] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:283800] 12 14.7 18.4 12.1 18.6 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:283800] 0.4667 0.3877 0.2521 0.5528 0.0704 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:283800] 0.0008 2.8321 6.6661 0 7.0045 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:283800] 11.5 11.5 11.5 11.5 11.5 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/06/2017 00:05:00" "11/06/2017 00:05:00" "11/06/2017 00:05:00" "11/06/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/06/2017 06:05:00" "11/06/2017 06:05:00" "11/06/2017 06:05:00" "11/06/2017 06:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 19.6 19.1 19.1 19.5 18.7 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 0.0621 0.0153 0.0905 0.2946 -0.2689 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0.6728 0.2223 0.0854 0.282 0.0761 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 18.9 18.9 18.9 18.9 18.9 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/07/2017 00:05:00" "11/07/2017 00:05:00" "11/07/2017 00:05:00" "11/07/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/07/2017 06:05:00" "11/07/2017 06:05:00" "11/07/2017 06:05:00" "11/07/2017 06:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 21.5 20.2 19.6 21.1 19.2 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 0.232 -0.277 -0.62 0.344 -0.985 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0 -0.819 -1.145 -0.58 -1.156 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 21.3 21.3 21.3 21.3 21.3 ...
##  $ :'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##   ..$ Interval                : chr [1:272448] "11/08/2017 00:05:00" "11/08/2017 00:05:00" "11/08/2017 00:05:00" "11/08/2017 00:05:00" ...
##   ..$ GMT.Interval            : chr [1:272448] "11/08/2017 06:05:00" "11/08/2017 06:05:00" "11/08/2017 06:05:00" "11/08/2017 06:05:00" ...
##   ..$ Settlement.Location.Name: chr [1:272448] "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##   ..$ PNODE.Name              : chr [1:272448] "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##   ..$ LMP                     : num [1:272448] 19 19 18.9 19.4 18.6 ...
##   ..$ MLC                     : num [1:272448] 0.1562 0.1086 0.0215 0.465 -0.3251 ...
##   ..$ MCC                     : num [1:272448] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
##   ..$ MEC                     : num [1:272448] 18.9 18.9 18.9 18.9 18.9 ...
```

Having done all that and seeing the URLs it retrieves:

```
https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171108.csv
```

You can really not even bother with all ^^ and just `sprintf()` or [`glue`](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue) the variable path components together for any given day of the year:

```
rtbm_lmp_by_location_by_day <- function(date) {
  date <- as.Date(date)
  y <- format(date, "%Y")
  m <- as.numeric(format(date, "%m"))
  ymd <- format(date, "%Y%m%d")
  sprintf("https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/%s/%s/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-%s.csv",
          y, m, ymd) -> fil
  res <- httr::HEAD(fil)
  if (httr::status_code(res) != 200) {
    message("File not found")
    return(invisible(NULL))
  } else {
    message(sprintf("Downloading <%s>", fil))
    read.csv(fil, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }
}

xdf <- rtbm_lmp_by_location_by_day("2017-11-08")
## Downloading <https://marketplace.spp.org/file-api/download/rtbm-lmp-by-location?path=/2017/11/By_Day/RTBM-LMP-DAILY-SL-20171108.csv>

str(xdf)
## 'data.frame': 272448 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ Interval                : chr  "11/08/2017 00:05:00" "11/08/2017 00:05:00" "11/08/2017 00:05:00" "11/08/2017 00:05:00" ...
##  $ GMT.Interval            : chr  "11/08/2017 06:05:00" "11/08/2017 06:05:00" "11/08/2017 06:05:00" "11/08/2017 06:05:00" ...
##  $ Settlement.Location.Name: chr  "AEC" "AECC_CSWS" "AECC_ELKINS" "AECC_FITZHUGH" ...
##  $ PNODE.Name              : chr  "SOUC" "CSWS_AECC_LA" "CSWSELKINSUNELKINS_RA" "CSWSFITZHUGHPLT1" ...
##  $ LMP                     : num  19 19 18.9 19.4 18.6 ...
##  $ MLC                     : num  0.1562 0.1086 0.0215 0.465 -0.3251 ...
##  $ MCC                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
##  $ MEC                     : num  18.9 18.9 18.9 18.9 18.9 ...
```

It shld be a straightforward process to figure out the patterns for the other categories.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks for such a detailed response. I thought about gluing the URLs as well, but the most recent ones are posted to the site at irregular times, so I thought I'd avoid attempting to download nonexistent files by scraping to get the URLs of the ones that were present on the page. Seeing how complicated the scraping is with the XHR request, it seems more straightforward to just wrap the call to `download.file()` I was running in a `tryCatch()` and ignore any Error 404s that come back for a user-defined list of file dates.

That's some serious scraping! Thanks again!

Comment: No need for `tryCatch()`. I made a slight modification to the latter "glue-ish" function to use `httr::HEAD()` to check for the status code before downloading. If it is anything but 200, it will return NULL and spew a message (but not an exception like trying to d/l the file would cause). That shld make logic a bit cleaner.